# Connect ECS instances from different task definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are testing the ECS infrastructure to run an application that requires a backend service (a MySQL) as well as a few web servers. Since we'd like to restart and redeploy the front end web servers independently from the elasticsearch service, we were considering defining them as separate task definitions, as suggested [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/application_architecture.html).

However, since the container names are autogenerated by ECS, we have no means of referring to the container running the MySQL instance, and `links` can only be defined between containers running on the same task.

How can I make a reference to a container from a different task?

PS: I'd like to keep everything running within ECS, and not rely on RDS, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is generally called service discovery, and there are a number of different alternatives.  ECS has integration with ELB through the [service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-load-balancing.html) feature, where tasks will be automatically registered in the ELB and deregistered in the ELB appropriately.  If you want to avoid ELB, another pattern might be an [ambassador container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/) (there's a sample called the [ecs-task-kite](https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-task-kite) that uses the ECS API) or you might be interested in an overlay network (Weave has a fairly detailed [getting started guide](http://weave.works/guides/service-discovery-with-weave-aws-ecs.html) for their solution).